# Maven doesn´t deploy related project if it's opened on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a core project (core-jsf) that is reference for other projects. It works fine, but I have to work around a strange behavior. This is what happends:

If the core-jsf project is Opened on Eclipse, when I try to deploy the subproject (on Tomcat), Maven doesn´t genarate the core-jsf JAR. And so, I can´t build the subproject because I get a bunch of ClassNotFoundDef.

My work around is: guarantee the core-jsf is closed on the workspace. You guys can imagine the trouble that brings me... Like debuging and test a new function on the fly and stuff.

This happended to anyone else? Any ideas how to fix this?
Let me show you guys some configuration...

Subproject's Dependency...

```
    <!-- Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.sol7</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-jsf</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Subproject's Deployment Assembly

[image]

The core-jsf project has JAR packing...
Any more info I can give to help out?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it isn't because of eclipse it's because of maven. Eclipse sees your dependency but meven doesn't (when you deploy).When you deploy eclipse use ative maven I think. Make sure that your dependencies were deployed before you deploy you project. 
I mean you can't deploy the project if you have dependencies to sources. In result you must have the dependency to some jar.